# Can't type password on login screen after upgrade ubuntu 16.04 LTS to ubuntu 17.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, login, 17.10

I just upgraded my ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 17.04. I did it from Software & Updates feature on ubuntu setting. Then after it has completed, i restarted my laptop (Acer). Then, it displayed the login screen. When i typed the password, it didn't show anything. Not even my password, it just displayed the mouse pointer.

Ofcourse, i've been searching similar issues over the internet. Unfortunately, i didn't found any solution that is same with me.

Any one can help me, please

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i know why this was happen to me. Unintentionally, I was removed the old desktop while upgrade to Ubuntu 17.04. Maybe, that's the main reason i thought.

This is how i fixed it :

1. Reboot my laptop
2. Hold on `Shift` key while computer boot into ubuntu
3. On `grub` window, choose **ubuntu recovery mode**
4. On recovery mode window, choose **root**
5. Install any desktop you want (in my case, i installed Gnome desktop)
6. After i installed the desktop, i rebooted my laptop
7. Finished

Answer (score 0):

So this might be a long reach but I had this issue once too. Go to recovery mode, as `root`

and run `apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all` (assuming you use Xorg)

That package was somehow uninstalled and I couldn't input anything. Hope it helps.